# Message: CompactToken parsing failed with error code: 8004920A , code : InvalidAuthenticationToken

Tags: php, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I want to create contacts with outlook in my application.Firstly, I get into this url below

`https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf?client_id='.$client_id.'&scope=wl.signin%20wl.basic%20wl.emails%20wl.contacts_emails%20wl.contacts_create&response_type=code&redirect_uri='.$redirect_uri`

I hope this is an old way to get the token,so I am

`https://login.microsoftonline.com/daa825ce-e4fb-40d2-b2e6-3a2f25e62b7c/oauth2/token?client_id='.$client_id.'&scope=wl.signin%20wl.basic%20wl.emails%20wl.contacts_emails%20wl.contacts_create&response_type=code&redirect_uri='.$redirect_uri`

So I get this error below.

http://prntscr.com/p4mb2c

Comment: Please post error as text, not as image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To [create contacts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-contacts?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http), you should call

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/contacts
Content-type: application/json

{
  "givenName": "Pavel",
  "surname": "Bansky",
  "emailAddresses": [
    {
      "address": "pavelb@fabrikam.onmicrosoft.com",
      "name": "Pavel Bansky"
    }
  ],
  "businessPhones": [
    "+1 732 555 0102"
  ]
}
```

You can follow [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user) to get the access token. Remember to grant your application `Contacts.ReadWrite` permission.

The scope in steps2&step3 should be `https://graph.microsoft.com/Contacts.ReadWrite`

**Update:**

To use personal account, you need to set the supported account type like below

[image]

And the authorize endpoint should use common, not the specified tenant.

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id=562855f4-f3dd-40bb-b829-515ccb96ff3f
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=http://localhost
&response_mode=fragment
&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/Contacts.ReadWrite
&state=12345
```

Also the token endpoint.

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token
```

Comment: I think it is the delegated permission in which user need to sign in for the app.If i need the user to add contacts in the background,so i don't need to sign in.I think it is the application permission.So whenever i try with the application permission,i didn't get the result & get the error "Resource Not found" or "Compact Token".Including this,are this service is free ? & i don't have to take any subscriptions in azure ? Maybe it is not fetching the response due to this ?

Comment: Whenever i hit this url for delegated permissions https://login.microsoftonline.com/daa825ce-e4fb-40d2-b2e6-3a2f25e62b7c/oauth2/authorize?
client_id=f9d70f3f-08c1-4df3-9f9a-f3ce24b572a3
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fmyapp%2F
&response_mode=query
&scope=offline_access%20user.read%20mail.read%20contacts.readwrite
&state=12345    I get " Access token validation failure. Invalid audience"   http://prntscr.com/p5863m   My code is above http://prntscr.com/p58rgn  http://prntscr.com/p58rms

Comment: @ahmadlatif1084 Do you want to create contacts for your personal account or azure ad account?

Comment: @ahmadlatif1084 This is not related to Azure subscription. Have you tried with Microsoft Graph explorer? https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer

Comment: @ahmadlatif1084 If you want to create contacts for azure ad account, the ad account must be assigned o365 license which is already an email address.

Comment: I have two accounts.First webmaster@thewichelentrading.onmicrosoft.com,which seems to be a work account and second rcgdeveloper1@gmail.com,which seems to be personal microsoft account.I tried from the graph explorer api from personal account in the website & it is creating contacts,but when i create from the source code it always gives me the above error.

Comment: Please see my code here After i hit the above url.   https://login.microsoftonline.com/b50e145a-852b-45aa-8289-10c3858f9905/oauth2/authorize?
client_id=644236e5-423d-40f5-8b0c-ad14d946822a
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A44322%2F
&response_mode=query
&resource=%3A%2F%2Frcgdeveloper1gmailcom.onmicrosoft.com
&state=12345          http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/jrvb-mep0

Comment: It works,but with the parameter response_mode=query.What if we want to create multiple contacts from single request ? Including this I am creating application mode,when user add contacts in background and no need to sign-in to create contacts.Please guide.

Comment: @ahmadlatif1084  If you use client credentials flow, I am afraid that you can only create contacts for tenant user.

Comment: I really appreciate your help,but can you please let me know what do you mean by tenant user and only client credentials flow ?

Comment: @ahmadlatif1084 You can only use client credentials to manage the users in your company(tenant/directory). Only personal accounts themselves can create contacts, which need to login.

Comment: I get from this that my personal account can only create contacts after sign-in,which means delegated permission.I can't create contacts from applications permissions ? Including this i am unable to differentiate between tenant and directory system & company accounts,as i am beginner with Azure Active Directory.Please refer to my new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57959691/nopermissionsinaccesstoken-in-application-azure-api-to-create-contacts/57961061#57961061. Thanks.