# NoPermissionsInAccessToken in Application Azure Api to Create Contacts

Tags: php, azure, azure-active-directory

There is an error of `NoPermissionsInAccessToken` while creating contacts in Application Permission in Microsoft Azure.

Here is my code: http://phpfiddle.org/api/raw/094u-5jm7/description and here is what I am passing http://prntscr.com/p6uiwx.

Answer (score 0):

It is really need to grant permission for the application you use, I assume you used the Azure Portal for revoke permission. The most likely reason is that you need to give relevant  permissions and should click the grant permission button,
For user authentication it is needed to give following permission for the application

Application permissions:

- Read directory data

Delegated permissions:

- Access the directory as the signed-in user
- Read directory data
- Sign in and read user profile

Comment: My question is why i have to grant delegated permission,as i don't want the user to signed-in,but the application runs in background & create contacts in outlook. I set the application permissions to this http://prntscr.com/p74cbh & resulting code is http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/jkbp-szx4,overall result is http://prntscr.com/p74dun.

Answer (score 0):

If you have already granted `Contacts.ReadWrite` **application** permission.

[image]

Then you must didn't **grant admin consent**.

[image]

For client credentials flow, you don't need delegated permissions.

> I get from this that my personal account can only create contacts
>   after sign-in,which means delegated permission.

You are right.

> I can't create contacts
>   from applications permissions ? Including this i am unable to
>   differentiate between tenant and directory system & company
>   accounts,as i am beginner with Azure Active Directory.

Not really, you can create contacts from application permission. But the accounts should be tenant user. Your tenant name should be something like `xxx.onmicrosoft.com`,your tenant user should be username@xx.onmicrosoft.com

[image]

**Update:**

For client credentials flow request, the scope must be `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default`

And make sure the account(tenant user) is an email address, or we can not create contacts for it.

[image]

Comment: This is my [code](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/wzg4-0wun) & the [steps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service) I am following,The background permissions are [this](http://prntscr.com/p7a5hu).But the problem is still there.

Comment: I tried again,but i found this [result](http://prntscr.com/p7b7m8).My portal configurations are [this](http://prntscr.com/p7b8ew) & my [code](http://phpfiddle.org/api/raw/ee8468f73b2f5a9031ff18d34f9f9dc9)

Comment: @ahmadlatif1084 This error doesn't make sense. I noticed that you were using common endpoint and client credentials flow. Where did it need tenant id? Is that tennant id yours?

Comment: I am getting the [access_token](http://prntscr.com/p7lahl) with this [permissions](http://prntscr.com/p7lat3), but still i get this [result](http://prntscr.com/p7lb9c) of NoPermissionsInAccessToken.

Comment: In addition, whenever is use this link https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token for token,it wouldn't get the user details by this link https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/.Only if i use tenant id https://login.microsoftonline.com/f547535c-4d4e-4ed9-97e8-762aadc01934/oauth2/v2.0/token, it would give me the result with https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/.

Comment: I have achieved batching in Microsoft Graph Api with delegated permissions somehow to store large set of contacts from a single request,i want to achieve exactly the same with application permissions,so if you give me the example of batching in application permissions would be most convenient.Thank you for your concerns.

Comment: @ahmadlatif1084 Can you decode the access token to check the scopes? https://jwt.io/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199630/discussion-between-ahmadlatif1084-and-tony-ju).

Comment: This is [header & payload](https://prnt.sc/p7q3xz) & this is [other part](https://prnt.sc/p7q4nj) of decoded access token.

Comment: @ahmadlatif1084 Use tenant id/name instead of common when get the access token, and you will find roles include in the access token.

Comment: These are the permissions i [get](http://prntscr.com/p84rvv),after i hit the [url](http://prntscr.com/p84t5a).The background settings are [this](http://prntscr.com/p84tpi) & [this](http://prntscr.com/p84u3f).Including this, the [jwt](http://prntscr.com/p84rvv) decoded values are given earlier,which [describes](http://prntscr.com/p84vof) the roles.Overall,this is my [code](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/drqa-2hnm).Please help & Thank you.

Comment: Should 'account(tenant user)' to be a **full email address** or just the part in front of the @ sign?